# MSAL authentication in Angular Logout redirect problem

Tags: angularjs, msal.js, msal-angular

Working on angular app with MSAL authentication and configured it with MSAL config factory and implemented in providers of the app module. I have provided a post logout redirect uri in the `publicclientapplication()`. When I logout for a small instance it redirects to the given page, but wont stay at it and goes back page before logout.

```
export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
    return new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: "",
        authority:"",
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200",
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/home",
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage
      },
    });
  }
  
  export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
    const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
    protectedResourceMap.set("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", ["user.read"]);
  
    return {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      protectedResourceMap,
    };
  }
  
  export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
    return { 
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      authRequest: {
        scopes: ['user.read']
      },
      loginFailedRoute: "./login-failed"
    };
  }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [....],
  imports: [....],
  providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: MsalInterceptor,
    multi: true
  },
  {
    provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
    useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
  },
  {
    provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
    useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
  },
  {
    provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
    useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory
  },
  MsalGuard,
  MsalBroadcastService,
  MsalService
],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**Login page**

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  isIframe = false;
  loginDisplay = false;
  private readonly _destroying$ = new Subject<void>();
  profile!: AccountInfo

  constructor(private authService: MsalService, 
    private broadcastService: MsalBroadcastService, 
    private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject(MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG) private msalGuardConfig: MsalGuardConfiguration){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.initialize().subscribe(()=>{
    this.isIframe = window !== window.parent && !window.opener;
    this.broadcastService.inProgress$
    .pipe(
      filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None),
      map(() => {
        const instance: IPublicClientApplication = this.authService.instance;
        const activeAccount: AccountInfo | null = instance.getActiveAccount();
        const accounts: AccountInfo[] = instance.getAllAccounts();
        if (activeAccount != null) return activeAccount;
        if (accounts.length > 0) {
            const [firstAccount] = accounts;
            instance.setActiveAccount(firstAccount);
            return firstAccount;
        }
        return null;
    }),
      takeUntil(this._destroying$)
    )
    .subscribe((account) => {
      this.getProfile(account)
      this.setLoginDisplay();
    })
    })
  }

  setLoginDisplay() {
    this.loginDisplay = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0;
  }

  login(){
    if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest){
      this.authService.loginPopup({...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest} as PopupRequest);
    } else {
      this.authService.loginPopup();
    }
  }
  logout(){
    this.authService.logoutPopup()
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._destroying$.next(undefined);
    this._destroying$.complete();
  }

  getProfile(account: AccountInfo) {
    this.profile = account
  }
```

**app-roots.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponentComponent},
  {path:  'user',canActivate: [MsalGuard], canActivateChild: [MsalGuard], children: [
    {path: 'create', component: CreateUserComponent},
    {path: 'configure', component: ConfigureGroupComponent}  
  ]}
```

I configured correctly upto my knowledge but wont redirect properly. And I am expecting my application to my home component which is not protected by MSAL Guard.